# how to compare two array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I had taken two array of objects in javascript

```
arr1 = [{"name":"prudhvi", "age":"12"},
        {"name":"pavan", "age":"13"},
        {"name":"prudhvi", "age":"15"}];

arr2 = [{"name":"Sai", "age":"12"},
        {"name":"Shiva", "age":"13"},
        {"name":"prudhvi", "age":"12"}];
```

1. Actually I want to compare both arrays **based on name only**. Here, name prudhvi is repeated I want to delete that object from `arr2`.
2. Another thing is I want unique items in `arr1`.  If there is any duplicate object, I want to delete it from this array.

Comment: Searching for your exact title bring up a lot of helpful information:https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+compare+two+array+of+objects+in+javascript

Comment: @JordanD, _JavaScript_, not Java.

Comment: @Andy this is javascript, not a java issue

Comment: @PaulRad, I know. What was the problem with the link I added?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper function for this, as the array contains new Object declarations (meaning they hold the same value, but won't reference the same Object as they're two separate entities). You should iterate over the array and see if it contains the expected value, and if so remove it. Something like this:

```
function removeDuplicateName( aArray, aName )
{
    var i = aArray.length; // get Array length

    while ( i-- )
    {
        var entry = aArray[ i ];   // get object at position i in array
        if ( entry.name == aName ) {   // object matches name
            aArray.splice( i, 1 ); // remove object at array position
            break;                 // if name is expected to unique, break operation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's an error in your code. `if (i.name == aName) {` should be `if (entry.name == aName) {`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a help function like...

```
function compareObjs( obj1, obj2, keys ){


    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){

        if( obj1[keys[i]] !== obj2[keys[i]] )  return false;

    }

    return !!keys.length;

}
```

this function 'll iterate in keys and return if all are equals...
SEE IN JSFIDDLE -> http://jsfiddle.net/dzkzL/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var diff = $(array1).not(array2).get();
```

if diff is null you have the same array otherwise it will contain the difference b/w two arrays